# How to programm a repeater?

Tags: wifi, routing

I didn't find any source-code online that showcases how to turn a wifi card into a repeater. From my basic understanding, a repeater copies whatever package it finds and resends them. Any thoughts welcome as I really didn't find anything out there.

Answer (score -1):

There are different ways of doing what you want.

You can use hostapd, a tool to create access points that has some configuration by editing the file `/etc/default/hostapd`and adding:

> DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"  # added to Hot Spot hostapd

And then creating the configuration file hostpad `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`

Or you can do it in a much easier way. In the computer's desktop bar, in the network icon, in network preferences, you can edit connections and create wireless access points.

> Note: In order to create an access point, you must have your computer connected via a network cable.

Comment: This describes creating an Access Point. It doesn't create a Repeater.